# Share via facebook - Xcode 4.2 with ARC

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to share a simple NSString via Facebook in my app. I am using Xcode 4.2 with ARC. Now, first i went to shareKit, but soon discovered that this won't work without using a lot of compiler flags and workarounds.

So now i'm looking for an easy-to-use Facebook sharing way? all i need to do is share a string via Facebook. So, the easiest way to get this done, while using ARC?

Thanks on advance guys.

Comment: Trust me `-fno-objc-arc` is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

ShareKit still is one of the best ways to do this, just simply have all the files in your project that don't use ARC have the `-fno-objc-arc` flag, like in the following image:

[image: Project->Targets->My Target->Build Phases]